# QFile/QDataStream writing on existing data

Tags: c++, qt, overwrite, qfile

I have got a file which is let's say 8 bytes length.
For example it looks like that:

`22222222`

Now, I read first let's say 5 bytes and changing them. For ex. to `11111`

Finally, I want to write them ONTO EXCISTING DATA to the file, so I expect the file to look like that:

`11111222`

But I get only `11111`, because file is erased. How can I disable erasing? (Maybe this question exists, but couldn`t find question like this one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you are exactly doing with the file, you might want to memory map it:

```
QFile f("The file");
f.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
uchar *buffer = f.map(0, 5);

// The following line will edit (both read from and write to)
// the file without clearing it first:
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) buffer[i] -= 1;

f.unmap(buffer);
f.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void fileopen()
{
QDataStream Input(&file);
Input>>"11111";
Input>>"22222";
file.close();
}
```

this function write the data.

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &ds,const QString &data)
{

ds<<data.toLatin1().data();
ds<<data.toLatin1().data();
return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the `QFile` with `| QIODevice::Append`, then `QFile::seek()`, then create the `QDataStream` on the `QFile` object. But note that `QDataStream` adds control information to the output, so that probably doesn't result in exactly what you want.

Also if you want to write text, not binary data, try with `QTextStream`.